# cassandra data modeling with e commerce and joins

Tags: cassandra

i am new to cassandra and I came from postgresql. I searched for cassandra e commerce data modeling and find this as example:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
  cust_id text,
  first_name text, 
  last_name text,
  registered_on timestamp, 
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_id));

CREATE TABLE Product (
  prdt_id text,
  title text,
  PRIMARY KEY (prdt_id));

CREATE TABLE Customer_By_Liked_Product (
  liked_prdt_id text,
  liked_on timestamp,
  title text,
  cust_id text,
  first_name text, 
  last_name text, 
  PRIMARY KEY (prdt_id, liked_on));

CREATE TABLE Product_Liked_By_Customer (
  cust_id text, 
  first_name text,
  last_name text,
  liked_prdt_id text, 
  liked_on timestamp,
  title text,
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_id, liked_on));
```

My Question is now, how can I join tables? If joins not working how you would speak to two tables?

Do you make for each table an request? make like this:

```
select * from customer where userid = 5;

row['userid'];

select * from product where userid = row['userid'];

and so on..
```

Because I heard joins are not available in cassandra so I have to do any requests like the example above or is there another solution?

I am very thankful for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right Cassandra does not support joins. In Cassandra you design your schema based on your queries. So you will have to have a schema which answers your query or you have to make multiple queries like in the exqmple above. There is no joins in Cassandra.